# pregunta sobre getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, método

Hola buenas soy nuevo en esto, no entiendo porque es necesario hacer un if aqui, (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia), si mi objeto mediaDevices y mi metodo getUserMedia es true entra en el bloque, pero podria omitir este paso no? No entiendo muy bien esa parte

```js
let video = document.getElementById('video');
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  //mediaDevices es sub-objeto, getUserMedia es metodo de mediaDevices
  if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) { // la segunda retorna true si objeto navigator si tiene mediadevices
    // then tecibe una function como parametro, then determina la respuesta a una espera si acepto o rechazo...

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }).then( function(reproduccion) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(reproduccion);//le doy como valor una url ficticia para el stream
      video.play();
    });
  }

  document.getElementById("foto").onclick = function() {
    video = document.getElementById('video');
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);// drawImage method recibe la imagen que es el video, 0 distancia del eje xy eje y, ancho 640 alto 480
  }
  console.log(typeof navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>getUserMedia API</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button id="foto">¡Sácate unas fotos!</button>

  <video id="video" width="640" height="480"></video>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>ç
  </body>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hace esa condición es comprobar que el navegador soporta esta funcionalidad.

Por ejemplo Internet Explorer u Opera Mini no lo soportan. El usuario también podría estar accediendo con una versión antigua de otros navegadores en las que no se soportara aún.

Comment: navigator.mediaDevices verifica que TIENE ESA funcionalidad y navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia entonces es true cuando 'SI LOS TIENE', los acepta tambien???
Gracias

Comment: Ten en cuenta que estamos hablando de funcionalidades que no tienen una especificación definitiva y que podrían no encontrarse implementadas o implementadas sólo en parte en los navegadores. `navigator.mediaDevices` comprueba que el objeto `navigator` tiene la propiedad `mediaDevices`, y `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` comprueba que el objeto `MediaDevices` devuelto tiene definido el método `getUserMedia`. Podría darse el caso que un navegador tuviese la funcionalidad parcialmente implementada y devolviese un objeto sin ese método.

Comment: Pense que mediaDevices era un sub objeto del objeto navigator no una propiedad... Pero has dicho 'tiene la propiedad mediaDevices'...

Comment: Es una propiedad del objeto navigator cuyo valor es un objeto